# jQuery add event for a selector that hasn't been "added" to page yet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` tag that gets added to the page depending on user variables (I'm using jquery append() to add it to the page)

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

I would like to have a click event for this div, but I think I am having problems because I am listening for the event before the div is added to the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#message').click(function() { console.log('clicked'); // no console message? };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally, [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) had to be used to achieve this. Since jQuery 1.7, however, [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred:

```
$(document).on("click", "#message", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

As an aside, if your markup contains a non-dynamic ancestor of your `#message` element, it's better to apply `on()` to that element instead, for performance reasons:

```
$("#non-dynamic-ancestor-of-message").on("click", "#message", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either delegate the event handling or add the event handler to the element before it is added to the DOM:

```
$(document).on('click', '#message', function () {...});
```

OR

```
var $message = $('<div id="message" />').click(function () { console.log('clicked'); });
```

Then whenever you append `$message` to the DOM it will have a `click` event handler attached: `$('body').append($message);`

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.delegate()`, however `.delegate()` has slightly different argument ordering.

- Docs for `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
- Docs for `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate